# Added @Transactional into a test to avoid org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException no Session error. Why is it needed?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I annotated a test method with `@Transactional` to avoid:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [com....OrderEntity#6def569a-ebf2-473e-b1b1-8b67e62fd17d] - no Session

    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor.intercept(ByteBuddyInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyConfiguration$InterceptorDispatcher.intercept(ProxyConfiguration.java:95)
    at com...orders.OrderEntity$HibernateProxy$wwLGAOuY.getDescription(Unknown Source)
```

I do not know why it is needed and wonder whether my application configuration is correct.

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
@Getter
@Setter
public class OrderEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID uid;
    private Date created;
    private Date updated;
    private String description;

}
```

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<OrderEntity, UUID> {

    List<OrderEntity> findByDescription(String description);
}
```

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

@Service
@Transactional
public class OrderService
{

    private OrderRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public OrderService(OrderRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public List<OrderEntity> findAll() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    public OrderEntity save(OrderEntity order) {
        return repository.save(order);
    }

    public OrderEntity getOne(UUID uid) {
        return repository.getOne(uid);
    }
}
```

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class OrderServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private OrderService service;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testSave() {

        OrderEntity order = new OrderEntity();
        order.setDescription("Order description");

        OrderEntity saved = service.save(order);
        System.out.println(saved.getDescription());

        OrderEntity persisted = service.getOne(saved.getUid());
        // throws LazyInitializationException without @Transactional
        System.out.println(persisted.getDescription()); 

        assertEquals(persisted.getDescription(), order.getDescription());
    }
}
```

I even added `@EnableTransactionManagement` but it makes no difference:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceJPAConfig {
}
```

Comment: Please share the source code for `OrderEntity`

Comment: @Vusal Added. Thanks!

Comment: Because you use `getOne` instead of `findOne`. `getOne` will ALWAYS return a lazy proxy and as soon as you start calling methods you will get exceptions (especially weird if there is no actual entity with that id). However as you aren't inside a transaction the session used to create the lazy proxy is closed. Adding `@Transactional` to the test will create a single tx spanning the whole test method (and rollback afterwards).

Comment: @M.Deinum Much appreciated! If you post it as a solution I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between `getOne` and `findOne` is that the first always returns a lazy proxy, even if there is no actual row in the database. The lazy proxy needs an open `EntityManager` to operate on. However as your test method doesn't run in a single transaction the `EntityManager` will be closed as soon as the `getOne`method ends.

Without an open `EntityManager` calls on the object will fail as it cannot retrieve the values from the database anymore.

To solve use `findOne` instead of `getOne` OR make your test method transactional. The latter however has some other effects on your test-case (it will return the same object from the `findOne` call as it will also reuse a single `EntityManager`).