# JUnit hibernate.LazyInitializationException

Tags: java, junit

I have simple example of One To many Bidirectional.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@Data
@Entity
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private Date createDate;
    private int rate;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Comment> comments=new ArrayList<>();
}
```

.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@Data
@Entity
public class Comment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String text;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    private Post post;

}
```

when i m make call

```
@GetMapping("post/{id}")
public Post getPost(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return postRepository.getOne(id);
}
```

[image]

Everything Okay 
But wen i m make @Test

```
@Test
void getPost() {
    Post post = postRepository.getOne(1L);
    System.out.println(post);
}
```

I have error

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [ge.cse.jpademo.model.Post#1] - no Session
```

[image]

How i can resolve this issue ?

I m try add @Transactional anotation and its works .

```
@Transactional
@Test
void getPost() {
    Post post = postRepository.getOne(1L);
    System.out.println(post);
}
```

.

```
Post(id=1, title=სატესტო პოსტი3, description=სატესტო კონტენტი, createDate=2020-05-19 02:26:16.237, rate=5)
```

But why i must  add  @Transactional in  @Test call and why its works in controller without @Transactional  ?

Comment: try implementing Serializable in both Post and Comment class

Comment: same result     : (

Comment: c an you please test another one? comment out this console print `System.out.println(post);` and just run, if works fine then uncomment and instead of printing whole `post` object, just print  post.getId/getDescription these parent class's elements

Comment: I'm comment // System.out.println(post);    after this run ass regular mode and test was green, but when im run as debug mode i see same Exception : "Method threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' exception. Cannot evaluate ge.cse.jpademo.model.Post$HibernateProxy$QLOjAsQi.toString() "

after this i try  System.out.println(post.getTitle());   - same result

Comment: remove `@Data` annotation, instead, add `@Getter and @Setter` annotations of lombok and can test in debug mode

Comment: removed all lombok annotation but same result

Comment: check this [similar issue with explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56034174/5332914)

Answer (score 0):

> But why i must add @Transactional in @Test call and why its works in controller without @Transactional ?

[**Open Session in View**](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-open-session-in-view) (`OSIV`) is enabled by default in `Spring Boot` applications and that could explain why your production code does not need `@Transactional` annotation on methods working with lazily initialized entities.
Having `OSIV` enabled, however, has its downsides and is considered to be [anti-pattern](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-open-session-in-view-anti-pattern/).